# What's that two-bracket or pair of slopes like schematic symbol next to a data line?

Tags: schematics, identification, symbol

I found this symbol in some datasheet. But I have no idea what is it? Can anyone tell me?

- The symbol is mirrored and points towards a data signal line
- It looks like an icon for a clock signal or a rising and falling slope or like two closing brackets

[image: Close up of that symbol]

[image: Schematic showing that symbol]

Comment: Gonna need some context. But it looks like differential signaling.

Comment: Another photo added

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TX_LED_N and TX_LED_P nets' naming convention says they are differential. It might be a instruction to the layout designer to route the lines strictly length matched tracks on PCB. It might also depend on the tool, the tool might automatically support pairing of differential signals and indicate the same via the symbol posted in OP. Below image from below link in comment.
[image]

Comment: This is correct. This is Altium's differential signaling directive. See here: http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/Using+Design+Directives+in+a+Schematic+Document